# Starting an action in a workflow based on a field in an InfoPath form

Tags: workflow, infopath

We have a Form Library in SharePoint for onboarding. Someone opens the form, fills out the details and Saves as a new form in the same library.

I have a workflow that then emails the Approvers group, and once they have approved the new user request it will then check if a radio button in the form is selected. If so, it needs to send an email and assign a task to someone to fill out the rest of the form. How can I do this in SharePoint Designer 2013?

The field in the InfoPath form is called 'm3Bool' with a value of 1 for No and 2 for Yes.

Comment: What you want exactly? Do you want to check radio button is selected or not? If yes, send email and task to that person from SP designer workflow?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd like to do.

Comment: Have you published InfoPath field in SharePoint form library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Publish InfoPath form again by adding `m3Bool` column in Wizard.

Image for reference:
[image]

Add following actions in SP designer workflow.
[image]

It will assign task and send email to requestor.